# How to dynamically load script in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having problem loading a script from within React side

This is the script:

```
<script>!function(e,t,s,i){var n="InfogramEmbeds",o=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],d=/^http:/.test(e.location)?"http:":"https:";if(/^\/{2}/.test(i)&&(i=d+i),window[n]&&window[n].initialized)window[n].process&&window[n].process();else if(!e.getElementById(s)){var r=e.createElement("script");r.async=1,r.id=s,r.src=i,o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o)}}(document,0,"infogram-async","https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");</script>
```

I tried something like this:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = scriptUrl;
script.charset = "utf-8";
script.async = true;
script.onload = function() {
    !function(e,t,s,i){var n="InfogramEmbeds",o=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],d=/^http:/.test(e.location)?"http:":"https:";if(/^\/{2}/.test(i)&&(i=d+i),window[n]&&window[n].initialized)window[n].process&&window[n].process();else if(!e.getElementById(s)){var r=e.createElement("script");r.async=1,r.id=s,r.src=i,o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o)}}(document,0,"infogram-async","https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");
};
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

If I add the script directly into header than it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is call the function inside componentDidMount and append the child into head like this

```
componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = 'https://www.google.com'; // whatever url you want here
        script.charset = "utf-8";
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = function () {
            !function (e, t, s, i) { var n = "InfogramEmbeds", o = e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], d = /^http:/.test(e.location) ? "http:" : "https:"; if (/^\/{2}/.test(i) && (i = d + i), window[n] && window[n].initialized) window[n].process && window[n].process(); else if (!e.getElementById(s)) { var r = e.createElement("script"); r.async = 1, r.id = s, r.src = i, o.parentNode.insertBefore(r, o) } }(document, 0, "infogram-async", "https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");
        };
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an npm package, a react hook to load a script dynamically. You can use that to load script dynamically in your react application. It will add script in the `head` or as child of any specified HTML element.
Here is the link to the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-script-loader